# Filtrar párametro por UID en Slim v3 PHP

Tags: php, rest, backend, slim

Estoy creando una API/resful con el framework slim php versión 3, el campo primary lo tengo en formato UID es decir uid es una cadena de texto con su estructura 'fce7f0be-bcbb-1bc4-5f83-b289f089742b'

parto de tener ese código
`$this->get('/{id:[0-9]+}', MyController::class.':get');`

he probado la siguiente regexpr pero no funciona

`^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$`

me devuelve 404, es como si la expresión regular no la procesase correctamente, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada, ya lo he solucionado solo con quitar el `^` y `$` me ha servido, ahora funciona perfecto

quedando así

`$this->get('/{uid:[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}}', MyController::class.':getOne');`

y en la parte de `MyController.php`

```php
public function getOne(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $this->logger->info(substr(strrchr(rtrim(__CLASS__, '\\'), '\\'), 1).': '.__FUNCTION__);

    $this->logger->info("uid:" . $args['uid']);

    $result = $this->dataaccess->get(_TABLE_, $args);
    if ($result == null) {
        return $response ->withStatus(404);
    } else {
        return $response->write(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
}
```